# How to write python unittest case for except block which just uses a logger statement

Tags: python, django, pytest, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

Code for celery task:

```
import logging

from celery_once import QueueOnce
from celery import shared_task, current_task
from test.set_data import set_data_in_db

logger = logging.getLogger("celery")


@shared_task(base=QueueOnce, once={"graceful": True}, ignore_result=False)
def set_data_task():
    try:
        logger.info("Set data in db initiated")
        set_data_in_db(value=None)

    except Exception:
        logger.error("data could not be set", exc_info=True)
```

My unittest case is covering everything which is in the try block. How can I force my unittest to cover except block as well ?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the method `set_data_task` , there could be only one situation out of two, either method executes normally (try block) or it throw some exception (except block).

If you need to test your `except` block , you need to configure your method to throw exception so that it could be caught and assert in your test

You will be in need to configure `set_data_in_db` method to throw exception to be caught

For testing exception, you can read [pytest.raises](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/assert.html)

Comment: `set_data_task` function is a periodic task which is scheduled using django celery beat. This function will just execute the `set_data_in_db` task, except block is just to log the the errors in case task fails. I don't want to raise any exception.

Comment: if you wont raise any exception , then how would you test it?? You have to raise exception to test it